# Co-Authoring and version control in Microsoft Word for Local Network

Tags: microsoft-word

My compny has a project being wirtten in microsoft Word. I would like to version control this document. The document will be modified by more than one person, so the version control of the file (built-in in Microsoft Word) won't work.

I know about shared point, but it's unlikelly to be used since we can't buy it just for that, and we can't leave the document on the internet (Microsoft Server) because it's confidencial.

Is there any other way to collaborativelly edit a version controlled Microsoft Word documet?

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/284239/how-to-use-office-2010s-co-authoring-tools) on the co-authoring tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. I don't know yet if there's a solution for this, but I used the Redmine plugin DMSF for revision control with a diff tool for Microsoft Word. Not the perfect solution, but for now it's filling in the blanks.